# What is timing for Global Conflicts Variant in through the ages?

Tags: variants, through-the-ages

When playing the Global Conflicts Variant (in the Handbook) points are awarded at the end of Ages 1,2 and 3 for relative military strength.  However what is the timing of this.

Does this happen as soon as age ends or do we go through all the other stuff such as leaders dying which may affect military strength.

Comment: Where can one read about this "global war" variant? A quick scan through google and the rulebook turns up no references to it at all.

Comment: The game come with two rules books.  "Code of laws" and "Handbook - Your first game". You need the hand book.  On the very last page at the bottom are several suggest variants.

Comment: For ease I'll paste it here.  "When Age I, Age II, or Age III ends, a global conflict occurs.
Each civilization scores culture equal to the difference
between its strength and the strength of the weakest
civilization. Thus, the weakest civilization will score
nothing."     I find it works very well with the peaceful variant where all agression and war cards have been removed.   helps keep military relevant with out weaker players losing to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ambiguity, but I would do the Global Conflict culture award first, and then follow the usual start of a new age process as defined in the rulebook.

- Discard antiquated cards
- Remove antiquated leaders from play
- Remove antiquated unfinished wonders.
- Remove antiquated pacts
- Lose 2 yellow tokens

This could be justified by noting the rulebook seems to list all those as something to do at the start of an age, while the culture award occurs at the end of an age.

Comment: i had a similar response on BGG.  in my head all those things happened at 'end of age'  rather than 'start of next age'  So the leader is alive for global conflict and may then die at start of next age.   When learning the game I made similar timing issues with card row being replenished at 'start of a players turn' and not 'end of previous player'.   I'll take this as correct answer then.